# I can't move files from one folder to another on a netatalk share

Tags: debian, network-share, apple, afp, netatalk

I'm running netatalk v. 2.1.2 on Debian Squeeze.  The clients are Mac OS X 10.7 boxes.  I have no problems copying files to and from the server, deleting files, creating new files or folders.

Everything seems to work perfectly except I can't copy from one folder on the share to another folder on the same share.  OSX reports errorcode -50.  Netatalk doesn't log the error anywhere I can see.

permissions are set correctly.  All users belong to the storageusers group and the sticky bit for the group is on the directory forcing all files and folders to belong to the storageusers group.  Permissions are 777 on the files in question in an effort to get rid of the error.

afpd.conf

```
- -transall --uamlist uams_randnum.so,uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so -nosavepassword -advertiser_ssh
```

AppleVolumes.default

```
/data/storage "storage" allow:@storageusers perm:0777 options:usedots,upriv cnidscheme:dbd
```

Am I missing something or is there a way to log the errors through netatalk?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? Thank you.

Comment: No, we ended up switching to Samba because of this and a few other issues with Netatalk.